# Jenkins - Is it possible to set a goal for X percentage of failed cucumber tests?

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber

We have a pipeline at the moment that executes a cucumber E2E job after the successful build of the BE. After the successful run of E2E we are planning on starting some other jobs. The question is.. Is there a way to set a goal on Jenkins so that after the successful run of E2E and IF pass test rate is over X percentage, then the job should continue?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If tests fail, why do you want to continue?

Comment: @JFabianMeier if eg 10% of tests fail then the job should fail and not continue

Comment: Yes, but if 1% fail, it should continue? Why? Why do you want to ship software with known test failures?

Comment: Yes because its its the dev environment and with 1% fail i want to be published in uat env

Comment: Why not fix the errors first? I would not bring something from dev to uat if I KNOW that there are bugs.